# Is there a utility to TRIM my Intel SSD (Gen 2 160GB)? Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, ssd

Is there a utility to TRIM my Intel SSD (Gen 2 160GB)? Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 (and so presumably Windows Server 2008 R2) does this natively: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/e7/2009/05/05/support-and-qa-for-solid-state-drives/

Comment: Note: most BMC and hardware raid controllers won't pass the trim command so even with a compliant OS you may not be able to trim the drive.